# AWS Lambda Environment Variables not set, process.env undefined in Node

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Even though the dashboard for the Lambda function shows me `NODE_ENV` listed as an environment variable, `process.env.NODE_ENV` is undefined when I run my Node AWS Lambda function.

This code...

```
console.log('node process env NODE_ENV:');
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

logs this:

```
node process env NODE_ENV:
undefined
```

I was wondering if it was a role issue, so I gave its role all permissions on AWS Lambda, but it didn't help.

For what it's worth, I'm using [Claudia bot builder](https://claudiajs.com/claudia-bot-builder.html), running the npm script

```
"deploy:production": "claudia update --version production --set-env NODE_ENV=production",
```

But like I say, the `NODE_ENV` environment shows in the list of environment variables in the dashboard for the function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

If you got here from a google search:

This could also happen when you define a function named "process" in your code. The function will override the internal node.js "process" variable.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out the problem was that Webpack compressed away `process.env`.

I got around the issue by using [babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables](https://github.com/babel/babili/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables), which inlines the environment variables at build-time.

Answer (score -1):

I found out as long as you put target: node in your webpack configuration, you will get access to the process.env variables.

Comment: what is `webpack configuration`?